# Rust cannot borrow as mutable

Tags: numpy, rust, numpy-ndarray, rust-ndarray

There are two ndarrays, a and b
I would like to parallel iterate through array a, and update array b at the same time.

`a.par_iter().enumerate().for_each(|(i, data)| { b[i] = data + 1; });`

However, I'm getting the message
"cannot borrow b as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a Fn closure"

I know that I could use par_iter_mut() instead, but this only enables mutable on a, but not b.

Comment: Aren't looking for something like [`par_azip`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/macro.par_azip.html)?

Comment: Couldn't use par_azip as the 2nd dimension of the arrays is different.
A is in dimension [n, m], 
B is in dimension [n, p], 
And I would like to iterate through the 1st dimension in parallel.

Comment: You should add [more context](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, we cannot guess...

Comment: If `a` is [n, m] then its iterator yields n*m items, which means you will get an out of bounds access for `b`.